# WCF - назначение UriTemplate?

Tags: c#, wcf

Добрый день.

Я здесь с вопросом, который никак самостоятельно не могу осознать.

> Вопрос: что такое UriTemplate и с чем его едят?

Я разбирал на конкретных примерах. Например:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:example:services")]
    public interface ISomeWcf
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "GetResult?client={client}&password={password}&messageId={messageId}")]
        string GetResultHttpGet(string client, string password, string messageId);

     }
```

В данном конкретном случае UriTemplate задает шаблон, по которому мы через REST-запрос можем обратиться к методу GetResultHttpGet. Читал МСДН, но не разобрался.

> Зачем указывать Namespace = "urn:example:services" ?

Можете подсказать, что с **UriTemplate** делать? Такое впечатление что рядом брожу с ответом, а сформулировать его не могу.

Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UriTemplate` задаёт шаблон, по которому определяется, должен ли входящий запрос с данным Uri быть направлен на обслуживание методом `GetResultHttpGet`, а также сопоставляет части Uri параметрам метода.

Допустим для данного контракта базовый адрес

```
http://hostname/SomeWcf/
```

Если приложением (или прямо браузером) сделать GET запрос

```
http://hostname/SomeWcf/GetResult?client=CLI&password=PWD&messageId=MSG
```

то будет вызван метод `GetResultHttpGet` сервиса. При этом части Uri станут значениями соответствующих параметров:

```cs
string GetResultHttpGet(string client, string password, string messageId)
{
    //здесь части Uri станут значениями параметров:
    //client = "CLI";
    //password = "PWD";
    //messageId = "MSG";
    ...
}
```

Если отклониться от шаблона, задав что-то другое, например

```
http://hostname/SomeWcf/GetResult2?name=NAME
или
http://hostname/SomeWcf/GetResult3/Name/Foo
```

то метод `GetResultHttpGet` вызван не будет.

Что касается свойства `Namespace` у атрибута `ServiceContract`

```cs
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "my.company.com")]
```

то оно фигурирует в заголовке soap-envelope

```xml
<s:Envelope ...>
  <s:Header>
    ...
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" ...>my.company.com/ISomeWcf/GetResultHttpGet</a:Action>
    ...
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body ...>
    ...
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Если его не указывать

```cs
[ServiceContract]
```

то вместо `my.company.com` там будет значение по умолчанию (`http://tempuri.org`).

Если интерфейс, описывающий контракт находится в сборке, на которую ссылаются и клиент и сервер, то в принципе `Namespace` может быть любым. Если же интерфейс описан дважды - в клиентской части и в серверной, или если вы создаёте клиента для уже существующего сервиса с определённым `Namespace`, то `Namespace` должны совпадать, чтобы клиент и сервер понимали друг-друга, иначе будет ответ

```xml
<s:Envelope ...>
  ...
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      ...
      <s:Reason>
        <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">
          The message could not be processed
          because the action 'http://tempuri.org/ISomeWcf/GetResultHttpGet'
          is invalid or unrecognized.
        </s:Text>
      </s:Reason>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```